# Xcode Environment Variable Macro for Version Number

Tags: xcode

I'm using KIF to build automated tests for my app. I have screenshots enabled by setting the `KIF_SCREENSHOTS` environment variable like so:
[image]

I'd like to add the current product version number to that path to achieve the result of:
`/Users/me/Desktop/kif-screenshots/1.0.7/myscreenshot.png`. I've tried the following macros, with no success: `$(VERSION_NUM)`, `$(CFBundleShortVersionString)`

Does anyone know what the macros are for version and/or build number that I can provide in this environment variable?